# Bootstrap dropdown within other inline text input fields

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

My problem is that I can't get the drop-down to display right underneath the drop-down field.  The drop-down values display to the far left of the column.

```
<input type="text" id="names[]" name="names[]" placeholder="Name" required>
```

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"  id="grade[]" name="grade[]" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria  expanded="true">Grade
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="grademenu">
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Third</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<input type="text" id=“grade[]” name=“grade[]” placeholder="Name" required>
```

Comment: Of course, I stumble on to the solution after posting.  I need to change:
    <div style="display:inline-block;">  TO <div class="btn-group">

Comment: Did you notice the change by adding the class `btn-group` that made the dropdown to display correctly?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: While `btn-group` worked, it isn't the ideal solution in your case as you don't have multiple buttons displaying to make it a **btn-group**. Ideal way would be to add a class `dropdown` (`<div class="dropdown">`). To explain: basically adding these classes relatively positions the parent div and as the dropdown-menu (ul) is absolutely positioned, it shows up correctly.